# Check file line by line, and determine if each line is pangram. But the code dosen't work properly?

Tags: java

I need to check a input text file line by line, and return true if it is pangram and false if not. But the code didn't work properly.

```
final int n = 26; 
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
    String line;
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.toUpperCase();
        if (line.length() < n) {
            writer.write("false");
            writer.newLine();
        }
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
            line = line.toUpperCase();
            if ((line.indexOf(c) < 0) && (line.indexOf((char)(c + 32)) < 0)) {
                writer.write("false");
                writer.newLine();
            }
        } 
        writer.write("true");
        writer.newLine();
    }
    br.close();
    writer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If the code's behavior is not as you expect it should be, then you need to do debugging first, perhaps using a debugger, and step through your code, checking variable state to see why it's wrong.

Comment: What does *"didn't work properly"* mean?

Comment: Why do you keep uppercasing the entire line over and over and over, as you check the letters of the alphabet? Why do you check for both uppercase and lowercase letter when you already converted line to all uppercase letters? Why do you continue to loop through all remaining letters of the alphabet after you find a missing letter and print `false`?

Comment: And why-o-why are you not using try-with-resources? Don't they teach this in school? If not, then why are you paying them to teach you?

Comment: Break your code into smaller parts - *divide et impera*. Especially separate the logic where you check if a String is an pangram, create a method `boolean isPangram(String s)` and call this method from the main loop. You will easily find your errors. And **test** your `isPangram()` method separately. Thus you will more easily see where your errors are.

Comment: You've called toUpperCase on line twice.

Answer (score 0):

You did quite a couple of mistakes. I fixed your code for now but please learn from those errors.

Also this is not the most optimal way of solving this issue and there are several things to improve on, like moving the inner for loop to its own method to save yourself from using labels. Also wrapping everything in a try/catch block is to be considered bad practice. Making sure your BufferedReader and BufferedWriter are closed even when an exception is thrown should also be considered. This could be done with try-with-resources (Java8 and onwards) or with a finally block (Java7 and earlier).

First, the fixed code:

```
        final int n = 26;
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
            String line;
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
            outerLoop: while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.toUpperCase();
                if (line.length() < n)
                {
                    writer.write("false");
                    writer.newLine();
                    // If you have already determined the line is not valid there is no reason to do the remaining loop iteration.
                    continue outerLoop;
                }
                for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
                {
                    // Removed this line as it was redundant. The line is already uppercase.
                    if ((line.indexOf(c) < 0) /* Removed the second check as you only work with uppercase letters. */)
                    {
                        writer.write("false");
                        writer.newLine();
                        // Once again: If you have determined the line to be false you should stop this check.
                        continue outerLoop;
                    }
                }
                writer.write("true");
                writer.newLine();
            }
            br.close();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

There are a couple major errors in your code and you should go back and reread a bit of the basics of coding in Java. But let's go over them really quick.

1.) You called line.toUpperCase() multiple times. The line is already in uppercase, you are being redudant.

2.) When you determined via `line.length() < n` that the line can not be a pangram you wrote false but still you did all the checking afterwards. You should continue your loop at this point so this iteration ends.

3.) You checked for a character to be equal to your character `c` and at the same time equal to the lowercase version of `c`. How is a character supposed to be equal to two values? ;) A `||` here would have been correct but is also unneccesary as you already made the String uppercase and therefore don't need to check for lowercase letters.

4.) Once again when you determined the line to not be a pangram with `line.indexOf(c) < 0` you did not continue your while loop.

5.) This leads to the last error. Your write always wrote true because your code always ended here.

---

How can you avoid such mistakes in the future?

1.) Make sure you read up on the basics again as your knowledge there seems a bit lacking currently.

2.) Learn about debugging your code. Should you use Eclipse for programming the following guide is a good starting point: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: Do not use labeled loops - if your loops are so complex that you need a label, split your code into smaller methods and call a method from the main loop. Then, use try-with-resources, your reader and writer does not close if any exception occurs before the code comes to the `close()` part.

Comment: While I certainly agree here and would have just moved the inner for-loop into its own method I wanted to not overcomplicate things here as the problem here seems to be fundamentally understanding how Java coding, AND and OR comparions and so on works.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your input suggesting the mentioned improvements :)

Comment: Well, where is the changed code? BTW, I think that by not using a method and by using several nested loops with a need for a label you in fact *overcomplicated things here* :) I have learned as a Java trainer that you should never show the learners even a slightly bad code - they are not in a state to distinguish when you are "simplifying" and they will start copying your style.

Comment: I did not change the code just added the suggestions as such before the code. Although showing bad code is probably bad practice changing the whole code is in my opinion too much here :)